# defining a new array of a specific type on F#

Tags: arrays, f#

How can I specifically define a new array of a specific type T ?

Strangely, I couldn't find any helpful information about it..

I want to write something like this:

```
let arr = new Array()
```

only that the elements of arr must be of type T.

How can I do it on F# ?

Comment: You said you could not find information about it; next time, start with the MSDN docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233181  The language reference has a subtopic called 'arrays' that would help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe the [`Array.init<'T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370582.aspx) and [`Array.create<'T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370553) functions are what you are looking for.

Also consider using a [`Sequence`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233209) instead of an array.

> A sequence is a logical series of elements all of one type. Sequences are particularly useful when you have a large, ordered collection of data but do not necessarily expect to use all the elements.

Answer (score 5):

If type of elements is unknown, you can use explicit type annotation:

```
let arrayOfTenZeroes = Array.zeroCreate<int> 10    
let emptyIntArray: int array = [||]
```

When you use high-order functions from [Array module](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370273), you don't have to do so since type of elements is automatically inferred by the type checker:

```
// arr is inferred as int array
let arr = Array.init 10 (fun i -> i+1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can try something like this.

```
let myStringArray : string array = Array.zeroCreate 10
let myIntArray : int array = Array.zeroCreate 10
let myCharArray : char array = Array.zeroCreate 10
```

It's described on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233214.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

[Automatic generalization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233183.aspx) and type inference are great features you should take advantage of.

When an array is created:

```
let arr = Array.zeroCreate 10
```

its type is *generalized*. In this case it's inferred to be `'T[]` (as general as possible).

Once you do something like:

```
let x = arr.[0] + 1
```

or

```
printfn "%s" arr.[0]
```

it can infer the concrete type (`int[]` or `string[]`, respectively).

The lack of explicit types makes your code much cleaner. Save type annotations for when they're truly needed.